# What do ? and : mean in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the Javascript/jQuery in this  http://www.queness.com/post/12078/create-jquery-pinterest-pin-it-plugin plugin. The lines 20 and 22 are confusing me, the code is:

```
pi_media = e.data('media') ? e.data('media') : e[0].src,

pi_desc = e.attr('title') ? e.attr('title') : e.attr('alt'),
```

Can anyone help me out with what these lines mean in Javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Sorry guys I don't know why I didn't see the exact duplicate. Feel free to close it.

Comment: Just so you're aware, the colon `:` also has two other meanings aside from its use in the ternary operator, assignment within the context of an object literal, and declaration of a label.

Comment: However the answers given on this page, seem more reference-like and higher quality, so perhaps there's value in keeping it open?

Answer (score 3):

It's the JavaScript [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
x = condition ? a : b
```

is equivalent to

```
if(condition)
    x = a;
else
    x = b;
```

Note that an assignment is not necessary. As an expression, it simply evaluates and produces `a` or `b` depending on the truth value of `condition`.

Comment: More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A

Answer (score 2):

It's called the [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a). It means:

- Evaluate the expression to the left of the `?`
- If the expression evaluated to `true`, run the first piece of code (between the `?` and the `:`)
- If the expression evaluated to `false`, run the second piece of code (after the `:`)

This is a construct common to many C-style languages.

Answer (score 2):

Those are part of the ternary operator.

Basically, if the condition before the `?` is evaluated to true, the expression immediately following the `?` is the one which is evaluated, and otherwise the expression following the `:` is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

For example take the code:
`var result=condition?arg1:arg2;`
First the condition is evaluated.
If the evaluation results to `true`, then `arg1` is returned and assigned to `result`
If the evaluation results to `false`, then `arg2` is returned and assigned to `result`